# Drawing a line in matlab plot

Tags: matlab

I am beginner in matlab programming, so i wrote this little programm to see it in action, and now I have a little problem because I am not sure why it is not working.

```
x = zeros(50);
squared = zeros(50);
cubed = zeros(50);

for num = 1:50
    x(num) = num;
    squared(num) = num^2;
    cubed(num) = num^3;
end

% calculate the mean
mean_cubed = mean(cubed);

% clear screen and hold the plot
clf;
hold on
    plot(x, squared);
    plot(x, cubed);
    plot([0, 50], [mean_cubed, mean_cubed]);
hold off
```

The main program is when i start the program i get a error:

```
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.

Error in basic_mathlab_plotting_2 (line 20)
    plot([0, limit], [mean_cubed, mean_cubed]);
```

I think the size of vector are the same, so i dont know what is wrong.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first lines, you probably meant

```
x = zeros(1,50);
squared = zeros(1,50);
cubed = zeros(1,50);
```

Note that `zeros(50)` is equivalent to `zeros(50,50)` and so it returns a 50x50 matrix.

In addition, those lines and the `for` loop could be replaced by

```
x = 1:50;
squared = x.^2;
cubed = x.^3;
```

This applies the important concept of [vectorization](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html), by using the [element-wise power](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/power.html) operation.